# Local/Inhouse Ads using AdMob

Tags: android, admob, local, ads

How can I show inhouse and local ads using AdMob? I want to show them among those retrieved from the Internet.

Should I put the inhouse Ads on the mobile, or should it be uploaded somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using admob you should use the Admob [House Ads](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=de&query=house%20ads&answer=1619751) Feature. This allows you to show one of your in house ads every time admob fails to load a relevant ad to show into you app. In this way you will not loose a single impression that could convert to a click on an ad but you are using your ad space for useful things if no ad can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get greater control over your ad inventory and tracking would be to manage them with [DoubleClick For Publishers](http://www.google.com/dfp/info/sb/index.html), which can then be set up with AdMob as the ad network through their SDK.